# Choosing Fields to Display Based on Radio

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

How do I go for instance only allowing the fields 'name' and 'email' show only if radio button "Professor" is chosen? Can someone show me how to do this in jQuery?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(':radio[name="addType"]').click(function() {

    $('#name-and-email-container').toggle(':not(:radio[value="Professor"]:checked)');

});
</script>
<?php
require_once('inc/dbc1.php');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=####;dbname=###', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT name
    FROM Department
    ;');
$sth->execute(array());
?>
<div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
    <h2 style="padding:0; margin:0;">Add a:</h2><br>
    <form action="inc/add_p_c_validate.php" method="post" id="addition"> 
        Professor<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Professor" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Course<input type="radio" name="addType" value="Course" /> 

        <div id="name-and-email-container">
            <br><br>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br> 
            Department: <select name="deptName" id="deptName"><?php while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo "<option>".$row['name']." "."</option>";} ?></select>   
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br></div><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
    </form> 
</div><!--popup_name-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be difficult at the moment with your current HTML, especially since your labels aren't in `label` elements.

Instead, wrap the name and email inputs and their respective labels in their own element.

```
$(':radio[name="addType"]').click(function() {
    $('#name-and-email-container').toggle(':not(:radio[value="Professor"]:checked)');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7ACAh/).

Comment: Please see updated code, this is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I know it works there :) . Do you see anything wrong with the updated code? Am I somehow not implementing it correctly?

Comment: I found the error. Forgot the document.ready :) . Thanks Alex !